# How to insert gps information to image?

Tags: python, python-imaging-library

Hi I am trying to get the GPS information and insert into another image. But its not working well.
I just want to get the information (GPS information, coordinates, ....etc) and insert to target image.

I am using PIL, piexif and exifread

Any help, thanks

```
original = exifread.process_file(open(r'/home/exif/original.jpg', 'rb'))
original

# original output:
{'EXIF DateTimeOriginal': (0x9003) ASCII=2020-07-04 16:35:21 @ 138,
 'GPS GPSAltitude': (0x0006) Ratio=263/100 @ 328,
 'GPS GPSAltitudeRef': (0x0005) Byte=0 @ 216,
 'GPS GPSDate': (0x001D) ASCII=2020:07:04 @ 464,
 'GPS GPSImgDirection': (0x0011) Ratio=5593/100 @ 456,
 'GPS GPSImgDirectionRef': (0x0010) ASCII=T @ 252,
 'GPS GPSLatitude': (0x0002) Ratio=[2, 54, 1029/100] @ 280,
 'GPS GPSLatitudeRef': (0x0001) ASCII=N @ 168,
 'GPS GPSLongitude': (0x0004) Ratio=[101, 23, 1309/25] @ 304,
 'GPS GPSLongitudeRef': (0x0003) ASCII=E @ 192,
 'GPS GPSTimeStamp': (0x0007) Ratio=[0/0, 1/0, 0/0, 1/0, 1/0, 0/0, 1/0, 1/0, 0/0, 1/0, 0/0, 0/0, 0/0, 0/0, 0/0] @ 336,
 'Image Copyright': (0x8298) ASCII=Copyright 2018 by Your Company @ 93,
 'Image ExifOffset': (0x8769) Long=124 @ 54,
 'Image GPSInfo': (0x8825) Long=158 @ 66,
 'Image Orientation': (0x0112) Short=Horizontal (normal) @ 18,
 'Image Software': (0x0131) ASCII=Creator(jstitcher) @ 74}


exif_bytes = piexif.dump(original)
target = Image.open(r'/home/exif/target.jpg')
target.save("/home/exif/target_out.jpg", exif=exif_bytes)


target_out = exifread.process_file(open(r'/home/exif/target_out.jpg', 'rb'))
target_out

# target_out output:
{}
```

I read the original image exif data and print the data.
Then I want to copy the output of the original image.
Then I want to insert to target image.

But when I print the inserted data to target image it is not inserted.
as the output shown above: ( {} ).

so my question is why it did not copied and how can i make properly.

Comment: Please provide more detail - you say "it's not working well", explain why and provide a complete error message.

Comment: Hi @DV82XL thanks for asking and commenting. I amended the post and I provided more details. tq

Comment: What is `type(exif_bytes)`? It needs to be a `dict` in order to work.